# Проблема в Open Server - "node -v не является внутренней или внешней командой"

Tags: openserver

установлен Open server....решил попробовать  Angular...так вот в чем проблема начинаю проверку в командной строке node js..то что node -v  не является внутренней или внешней командой   чет я не понимаю

Comment: **install /full/path/to/node /usr/bin/**

Answer (score 1):

**Openserver**, это набор программ для удобной веб разработки на локальном сервере - на своём компьютере. Туда входит:

1. *веб-сервер - apache, nginx*
2. *php интерпритатор*
3. *база данных - mariadb mysql, postgreesql, mongodb*
4. *набор дополнительных утилит. phpmyadmin - управление базой данных.*
5. *memcached, redis, dns службы*
6. *ftp и почтовый сервера*

**nodejs** туда не входит, вам нужно его установить отдельно , https://nodejs.org/en/ . Он пропишется в вашу систему и вы сможете выполнить

> node -v

Comment: вы забыли про mysql

Comment: так стойте у меня он висит в процессах разве он не установлен?

Comment: но со ровно попробую

Comment: если установлен попробуйте вызвать его из папки напрямую, "C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\bin\node.exe -v" / Или прописать его в системную переменную PATH. кажется он у вас не проинсталирован.